# Translating PowerPoint VBA code to Delphi, "keep source formatting" issue

Tags: delphi, powerpoint

I am working with Delphi(2010), but I'm new with PowerPoint(2010)

I've found two codes for copying slides with "keep source formatting":

```
Sub test1()
Dim orig_slide, new_slide As Slide
Dim slide_range As SlideRange

    Set orig_slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    orig_slide.Copy
    Set slide_range = ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste(6)
    Set new_slide = slide_range.Item(1)

    new_slide.Design = orig_slide.Design
    new_slide.ColorScheme = orig_slide.ColorScheme
End Sub

Sub test2()
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select
    ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial (DataType = ppPasteOLEObject)
End Sub
```

They both are giving desired results in PowerPoint but in Delphi i get exceptions :

test1, line

```
new_slide.Design = orig_slide.Design
```

exception class EOleSysError with message 'Member not found'

test2, line

```
ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial (DataType = ppPasteOLEObject)
```

exception class EOleException with message 'View.PasteSpecial : Invalid request.  The specified data type is unavailable'

I am using Slide Sorter View, copying and pasting are working ok, I'm only trying to add "keep source formatting" command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to, but I can't see "check mark beside the answer". Maybe because I'm new user, maybe I can't answer my own questions ...

If you have time, please post some some dummy answer so I can accept it, or explain me some other way to mark question as answered.

Thanks

Comment: I can't see your answer, you've probably didn't `Post Your Answer` :)

Comment: I couldn't answer to my post at first, I got some restriction (preventing of making self-reputation).

Now it's enabled, I guess because I received your comments or some time has passed ...

Thanks TLama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a solution :

This code in Delphi (doesn't work)

```
var OrigSlide, NewSlide : Variant;
NewSlide.Design := OrigSlide.Design;
```

on the right side, Delphi seems to accept only variant_variable, it doesn't accept variant_variable.property

Left side seems to work in opposite way ?!?

When I replaced it with this code, it works

```
OrigSlide := OrigSlide.Design;
NewSlide.Design := OrigSlide;
```

But I can only guess why.